# can "should" be used as a modal auxiliary verb for emphasis in a conditional?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Based on the grammar books, for example,
https://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/auxiliary.htm

"Do & did" are used as an auxiliary verb for emphasis as in

> He does like spinach
>
> He never did understand his father

While there are a few examples where "should" is used as an auxiliary verb for "emphasis" as in

> I should imagine they'll vote Conservative.
>
> I should have thought so

is it appropriate, confusing or downright wrong to use "should" as a modal auxiliary verb in a conditional sentence for "emphasis", as in

> I apologize if I should change the rituals without consulting the
> elders.

Comment: You asked the same question on other another grammar website. What did you learn there?

Comment: @Bill, my other question was similar but not identical (to me). While your answer there did help, the new resource provided an example - I should imagine they will vote Conservative - that "should" can be used for emphasis (unless I misunderstood the meaning of "emphasis")  Hence the new question.